# Failing to recursively filter multidimensional array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a variable which may be an object or an array.  If it is an array, it will be of objects.  Each object may have a parameter which is another object or an array of objects.  All arrays may be n levels deep.

All objects have a parameter 'isAccessible'.  The value of this parameter may be true or false.

If it is false, that object must be removed from the structure.

I have tried array_filter and because I was not able to recursively filter as described, I have written a home rolled recursion function.

However I have not been able to get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
public static function jsonGateway($json) {
    $object = json_decode($json);
    $newJSON = '';

    // $object may be a stdClass Object or it may be an array of stdClass Objects
    // An objects parameters may be a string, integer, or an array of stdClass Objects.
    // This function must recurse arbitrarily deep
    // Any object where isAccessible = 0 must be purged (numeric string or int?)

    if (is_object($object)) {
        if ($object->isAccessible == 1 || $object->isAccessible == '1' || $object->isAccessible == true) {
            $newJSON = $json;
        }
    } else if (is_array($object)) {
        $newJSON = json_encode(self::filterRecursive($object));
    }

    echo $newJSON;
}

public static function filterRecursive(Array $source) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $object = $value; // Just a comprehension aid
            if ($object->isAccessible == 1 || $object->isAccessible == '1' || $object->isAccessible == true) {
                // Keep this object
                // This objec though, may have a parameter which is an array
                // If so, we need to recurse
                $objectVars = get_object_vars($object);

                if (count($objectVars) > 0) {
                    foreach ($objectVars as $objectParameter => $objectValue) {
                        if (is_object($objectValue)) {
                            if ($object->isAccessible == 1 || $object->isAccessible == '1' || $object->isAccessible == true) {
                                $object[$objectParameter] = $objectValue;
                            }
                        } else if (is_array($objectValue)) {
                            $object[$objectParameter] = self::filterRecursive($objectValue); // Line 177
                        }
                    }
                }

                $result[$key] = $object;
            } else {
                // don't need this block
                error_log("deleting: " . print_r($object,true));
            }
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array = $value; // Just a comprehension aid
            $result[$key] = self::FilterRecursive($array);
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Not only am I not succeeding at filtering anything, I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home1/lowens/public_html/dev/classes/Lifestyle/RBAC.php on line 177
```

Can you help?

Comment: Where in your code is line 177?

Comment: Which is `line 177`? You can just pass `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode()` which will convert objects into associative arrays for you.

Comment: It's marked, but it's on a long line and you need to scroll right.  $object[$objectParameter] = self::filterRecursive($objectValue); // Line 177

Comment: I've gotten past the 177 problem.  I was assigning $object[$objectParameter] when I should have been doing $object->$objectParameter.  But I am still not filtering out objects where inAccessible is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
public static function filterArray(Array $array) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $newObject = self::filterObject($value);
            if (count(get_object_vars($newObject)) > 0) {
                $result[$key] = $newObject;
            }
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            $newArray = self::filterArray($value);
            if (count($newArray) > 0) {
                $result[$key] = $newArray;
            }
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param \stdClass $object
 * @return \stdClass
 */
public static function filterObject(\stdClass $object) {
    $newObject = new \stdClass();

    if ($object->isAccessible == 1) {
        $objectVars = get_object_vars($object);

        foreach ($objectVars as $objectParameter => $objectValue) {
            if (is_object($objectValue)) {
                $newObject->$objectParameter = self::filterObject($objectValue);
            } else if (is_array($objectValue)) {
                $newObject->$objectParameter = self::filterArray($objectValue);
            } else {
                $newObject->$objectParameter = $objectValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $newObject;
}
```